# No binding of arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain me the behavior of this code?

```
var arguments = 42;
var arr = () => arguments;

arr(); // 42

function foo() {
  var f = (i) => arguments[0] + i; // foo's implicit arguments binding
  return f(2);
}

foo(1); // 3
```

I know what *implicit arguments binding* is.

- What I don't understand is how `foo(1)` is returning **3**?
- What does `return f(2)` does? As in which function it calls?

PS: I'm following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Mozilla docs.

Comment: Inside `foo`, `argruments[0]` has `1` value, since argument of `foo` is `1`. `f(2)` is calling the function `f` with argument 2 which invokes the arrow function and add 2 to argument[0] which was 1. Hence, the output is 3.

Comment: @HassanImam where is function `f` ?

Comment: `var f = (i) => arguments[0] + i;` this is your function `f`.

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks for explaining. Now, I get it. :)

Comment: Glad to help you man! :)

Comment: @HassanImam What will be the value of `var f` when the function is called as `foo(1)` before execution of `return f(2)`?? **Note**: before return (In second line of the function) we don`t have a value for `i`.

Comment: `f`will hold the reference to arrow function. When you pass a variable to it, then it will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this a little clearer for you I'll re-write it as ES5

```
function foo(){
   var arg1 = arguments[0]; // argument is 1 in your example
   var f = function(i) {
      return arg1 + i; // i is 2 in your example
   };
   return f(2); // returns 3
}

foo(1); // sets argument to 1 and returns 3
```

In ES6 arrow functions do not have an arguments property like standard functions. You're accessing the foo function arguments array like object. As the first argument you passed in is 1, the arrow function accesses the foo function arguments object and retrieves the first value within the arrow function.

Comment: So `var f` will be undefined till the execution has reached to `return f(2)`?? As `i` have no value assigned to it initially.

Comment: No it won't be undefined. <edit>It'll be undefined until the JavaScript interpreter hits the var f declaration</edit>  The value of f will be an arrow function once the interpreter executes the var f declaration. It'll return a value when you call it. e.g. f(2);

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions do not bind `arguments` so when you use `arguments[0]` inside `f` you are accessing `foo`'s arguments (ie `1`). Since you have passed 2 as `i` you get `1 + 2`

For example if you use an arrow function that tries to access arguments outside of a function call you should get a `ReferenceError`

```js
const f = i => console.log(arguments[0])
try {
  f()
  console.assert(false, 'should not get here')
} catch (e) {
  console.assert(e instanceof ReferenceError, 
    'should get reference error on trying to access arguments')
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of `var f` when the function is called as `foo(1)` before execution of `return f(2)`?? **Note**: before return (In second line of the function) we don't have a value for `i` till we have reached `return` function.

Comment: The value of var f will be an anonymous arrow function. It won't be an explicit value until called, just like a regular function. Once you call it, it will return the value of arguments[0] + 1

Comment: Initially `var f` is `undefined` due to hoisting then you assign an arrow function to it. So after you assigned an arrow function to it it holds a reference to that arrow function. Doesn't matter if you called it or not.

Comment: Just try to log it `function foo() {var f = i => arguments[0] + i; console.log(f); return f(2)} foo(1);`